# JQM grouping by category

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

Hei. Grouping works fine exept when I tried to add some category items count. After adding this, items stop group according to their category. Is there a way to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/smatisen/md17azga/

```
$('.todo-listview').on("afterRefresh", function () {
    $(".ui-li-divider").each(function () {
        console.log($(this).text());
        var textSplit = $(this).text().split(",_#_");
        var countValue = textSplit[1];
        console.log(countValue);
        $(this).text(textSplit[0]);

        var count = document.createElement('span');
        $(count).addClass('ui-li-count').text(countValue);
        $(this).append(count);

    });
});

$('.todo-listview').listview({
    autodividers: true,
    autodividersSelector: function (li) {
        var out = li.data("category");
        var ranomNumber = $('li[data-category="' + out + '"]').size();
        if (out == "") {
            return "A Table Is Not Set";
        } else {
            return [out, "_#_" + ranomNumber];
        }
    }
}).listview("refresh").trigger("afterRefresh");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .length instead of .size() to get the count, and instead of returning an array, just concatenate the string (`return out + "_#_" + ranomNumber;`)

```
 $('.todo-listview').listview({
     autodividers: true,
     autodividersSelector: function (li) {
         var out = li.data("category");
         var ranomNumber = $('li[data-category="' + out + '"]').length;
         if (out == "") {
             return "A Table Is Not Set";
         } else {
             return out + "_#_" + ranomNumber;
         }
     }
 }).listview("refresh").trigger("afterRefresh");
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/md17azga/1/)**

Comment: It seems that works, although new challenges arise. Le us see what can be done. Thank you.